# Could Web components (JavaScript native) be registered in the end of HTML's body?

Tags: javascript, web-component

Can I build my JavaScript application to single bundle file including Web Components and link it to end of `body`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- must work -->
    <local-example_component></local-example_component>

    <!-- includes "local-example_component" implementation -->
    <script src="Application.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does NOT matter WHEN the `customeElements.define()` script is executed

Source:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#upgrades

> Custom elements can be used **before** their definition is registered.
>
> Progressive enhancement is a feature of custom elements.
>   You can declare a bunch of  elements on the page
>   and never invoke `customElements.define('my-element', ...)` until much
>   later.
>   This is because the browser treats potential custom elements
>   differently thanks to [unknown tags](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#unknown).
>   The process of calling `define()`
>   and enriching an existing element with a class definition is called
>   *"element upgrades"*.

---

You can load/inject/execute script anytime:

```js
  function upgrade() {
    customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = this.nodeName + ' defined!!';
      }
    })
  }
```

```css
  body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }

  *:not(:defined) {
    color: red;
  }

  my-element {
    color: green;
  }
```

```html
<my-element>&lt;my-element>unknown Element&lt;/my-element></my-element>
<br>
<button onclick="upgrade()">
  Upgrade
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the good answer! And I am sorry, I has not enough knowledge to understand that previous answer was wrong. That why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

Script can be loaded any where in html. However, It is suggested to before body inside `head` with defer attribute statement.

`The defer attribute is a boolean attribute. When present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.`

**Basic def:** https://w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

> **There few more supporting docs and best practice can be found**

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements

`<script defer src="main.js"></script>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Life cycle callbacks test</title>
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Life cycle callbacks test</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

Look at the example:'

https://github.com/mdn/web-components-examples/blob/master/life-cycle-callbacks/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How behavior will change if to move `<script defer src="main.js"></script>` in the end of body? In the both cases, scripts will be executed when page will be loaded (as far as I understood the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Properties)): "If the async attribute is absent but the defer attribute is present, then the script is executed when the page has finished parsing."

Comment: all element need to be parse has to be above, else interpreter cant parse the DOM element.

Comment: So, although in the head with `defer` attribute script will not be executed instantly, browser will parse it before render anyHTML?

Comment: but it warn compiler, that COVID 19 will come in futute, Be prepare. Not like China :(

Comment: O'K, thank you for the explanations. Accept & up-vote.

Comment: But the answer is wrong... so we can classify it as 'Fake news'?

Comment: Serious, **you can load** and execute a define-Element script **at any time**. The Browser will do a reflow and ``upgrade`` existing unknown elements. No strict requirement to place scripts in the HEAD or 'above' Custom Elements.'

Comment: Please read!. `The defer attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.`

Basic def: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: @xdeepakv, Please update your answer to prevent of being downvoting.